# What is the way to quickly undo a change I pulled in git?

Tags: git, github

If i pull a change on my server and then suddenly realize i broke something accuse I'm an idiot. what is the quickest way to undo what I just pulled.

my workflow:

- change stuff on my computer, make sure it works, push to github
- ssh into server, pull changes

what if I suddenly realize the changes I pulled broke something and I want to quickly go back?

Comment: try `git reset --hard OLD_COMMIT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the fastest way is `git reset --hard OLD_COMMIT`

If you don't know the `OLD_COMMIT`, then `git reflog` might help - usually (if you did not do anything after pulling) you can also use `HEAD@{1}` directly

Do not use git reset if you had local modifications in the working tree.